# Errors Trying to Install Craft Commerce on MAMP Pro

Tags: plugins, plugin-craftcommerce, installation, mamp

I've installed Craft Commerce locally on MAMP Pro a few times. When I click the install button it takes awhile and then finally I get a 500 Error.

My Apache Log shows only these two lines:

```
[Thu Jun 09 15:09:06 2016] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.0.0.fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec), referer: http://craft-prototype.dev/admin/settings/plugins
[Thu Jun 09 15:09:06 2016] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.0.0.fcgi", referer: http://craft-prototype.dev/admin/settings/plugins
```

After I receive the error if I go to `/admin/settings/plugins` the plugin will show as installed and it's completely fine. The issue doesn't happen when I try to uninstall it. The issue will still happen even if I uninstall and reinstall it.

I should also mention that the Craft CMS install and all other plugins are working great and I receive no other errors until this comes up.

I'm assuming this is probably a MAMP configuration issue. Has this come up for anyone else?

Comment: Damn. Yup, it's a dupe... this clearly fixed it for me. I found a similar solution that wasn't as clearly written so I couldn't get it going but the selected answer here solved it for me.

Comment: Awesome, glad you're sorted! Going to to ahead and vote to close this as a dupe, then.